# I want to display default value in drop-down with ngModel attribute. but I am not getting default value

Tags: angular, ngmodel

<select (change)="selectlang(langSelected.value)" [(ngModel)]="details.language">

{{language.localeCode}}l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xgveuu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Use the below code , in html app.component.html

```
<select (change)="selectlang()" [(ngModel)]="selectedlang">
    <option  *ngFor="let lang of details">{{lang.localeCode}}</option>
</select>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  selectedlang='EN'
  details =[{
    name:'a',
    language:'english',
    localeCode:'EN'
  },
  {
    name:'b',
    language:'arabic',
    localeCode:'AR'
  }
  ]
  selectlang(){
console.log(this.selectedlang)
  }
}
```

you need to give a value to **selectedlang='EN'** (you like)